Custom Request body for swagger - Spring boot
I came through with an requirement where I should have String as input type in request body for an api but in the swagger it should show as JSON Model, So it gets easy to read for other people.
I am using Swagger 3.0.
I am looking for similar to @APIResponse which is helping to change the response type.
I have gone through with all below urls but didn't find much information.
Let me know if you need any other inputs.
Java Spring Boot OpenApi 3 - How to add description for RequestBody?
Cannot import @ApiParam or @ApiModelProperty annotation even though Swagger is added as Maven dependency
How can I set a description and an example in Swagger with Swagger annotations?
https://www.bezkoder.com/swagger-3-annotations/

